# Aggregate PageViews For All Traffic - Google Analytics

Tags: c#, google-analytics

I've written code to query Google Analytics and get the top pages of a site. The problem is when getting the most viewed pages, there are "duplicate" page paths are being shown.

After some investigation, it seems as if the pages are "duplicated" due to URL shortners that add different params to the page

Is there a way to filter or have a query that gets the top pages and uniquely filters the page path?

Below is currently how I implement the query in C# and attached is the query I use in the Query Explorer.

```
DataResource.GaResource.GetRequest request = service.Data.Ga.Get("ga:" + this.viewId + "", "today", "today", "ga:pageViews");
request.Dimensions = "ga:pagePath,ga:pagePathLevel1,ga:pagePathLevel2,ga:pagePathLevel3,ga:pagePathLevel4,ga:pageTitle";
request.MaxResults = 20;
request.Sort = "-ga:pageViews";
```

[image: Query Explorer]

Comment: If you do not want a breakdown by referrer then remove the referrer from your dimensions (I might misunderstand what your are asking, though).

Comment: @EikePierstorff, Sorry about that I'll update my image now, even taking out the referrer from my dimensions still produces "duplicate page paths" but less than having it in.